# Windows server 2019 install not showing GUI options

Tags: windows, windows-server-2019

I've downloaded the latest ISO (December 2019) for Windows Server 2019. When I go to install on a new server the list of install options only includes the core non-GUI install options.

How do I install Windows Server 2019 with a GUI (desktop experience) option. All the website I view indicate that there should be four options in the dialog below, where I only see two.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These days Windows server comes not only in different editions but also in different types:

**Long-Term Servicing Channel** - This is usually the initial release of a server, and it gets monthly security updates, but no new features. It also can not be freely upgraded to a newer version of the server as is the case for Windows 10 clients.

The current version is Windows Server 2019 - 1809

This version has both Server Core and full server (desktop experience).

**Semi-Annual Channel**

This has two releases each year, in 2019 it had versions 1903 and 1909

This type only comes with Core editions, no desktop experience. If you want a desktop you have to use the last `Long-Term Servicing Channel` version.

It seems you downloaded 1909 which is the latest `Semi-Annual Channel` and has no Desktop option.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started-19/servicing-channels-19#why-do-semi-annual-channel-releases-offer-only-the-server-core-installation-option

Comment: This was correct. When I downloaded just Windows Server, rather than the December update it included the desktop experience options.

Answer (score 2):

On some Windows 2019 editions, the GUI is installed by default. You can simply select "Windows server standard".

Comment: Must be depending on the image. Just yesterday I installed a 2019 server where I had to choose between GUI and non-GUI.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider yes, it sounds possible

Comment: How do I find the image with that option? Both of the options I have are for the Core version without the GUI. Does it maybe just not exist in the ISO I downloaded and I should try another?

Comment: Can you share the name of the ISO you downloaded?

Answer (score 0):

You can look for a command to install the GUI feature, from inside your core command prompt. Search for Powershell command Add-WindowsFeature server-gui-shell, server-gui-infra (or something like that). It's always possible to come and go with the GUI using the powershell to Add or remove the features. Good luck.

Comment: This worked for Windows Server 2012 (R2) but no longer works for 2016 and 2019. If you installed Core, you are stuck with Core.